# Merging the tags configuration and settings?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Are these really two different things -- or should we merge [configuration](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/configuration) (x21) and [settings](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settings) (x156), making `configuration` a synonym to `settings`?

**Hint:** The tag description of [settings](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/settings) reads:

> Questions related to Android Mobile Settings and Configuration.

I let that speak for itself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreed, done.

Comment: Thanks! But what about the synonym? Not useful? I just think of future tagging by new users. Description currently says: *settings currently has no approved synonyms*.

Comment: @Izzy I selected that option ... just tried again and it still didn't work.  Maybe it takes a bit to show up?  Not sure why they would cache synonyms....

Comment: It just says "no approved". Maybe it needs somebody to approve? I wonder, as your rep should be high enough. If you marked it for synonym, that's all I can ask for -- so I'll try to be patient and faithful it will work out. Otherwise I'll ask for a new merge in a couple of weeks xD Thanks again!

Comment: I can't quite confirm it for sure, but it actually appears that the merge + synonymize functionality might be broken. I merged two tags yesterday and marked for them to become synonyms, but it doesn't appear to have been applied. I had to go in and do it manually just now to make it show up as a synonym (/cc @Izzy just as an FYI)

Comment: @eldarerathis Thanks for confirming our suspicion -- and of course for fixing it for the current cases! So let's hope the techs get it fixed soon :)

Comment: @eldarerathis Are the devs aware of it?

Comment: I haven't reported it on Meta or anything, but I don't know that I have enough information myself to confirm it at the moment. Though if it did happen to you here (and you're fairly certain you checked the "synonymize these" box) then that might be enough to go on. I personally can say I certainly *thought* I had checked the box to create a synonym on the tags I merged yesterday, but I can't say with 100% certainty that I actually did.

Comment: @eldarerathis Great thanks, I'll report it.