# Synonymizing tags during merging does not work

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms

It seems that synonyms aren't being created when the `These two tags are synonyms and mean the exact same thing` is checked during a merge.  Both eldarerathis and I had a problem with this, see the comments [here](https://android.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1126/1465) for more info.

Comment: And if it's helpful, two merges in question were `repeating-reboot` into `boot-loop` and `configuration` into `settings`.

Comment: I merged two tags just now and made double-sure that I checked the "synonymize" box. It did not work, so I think I can confidently say this functionality is not working at the moment.